# Xamarin.Forms - Save files out of app Directory

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin.forms Media.Plugin and it works well. But I need to save the image out of app directory, like de Download Path or DCIM Path. How to do this ?

Comment: Just copy the image file wherever you want it to go

Comment: could it work ?

Answer (score 0):

you could look at the documentation for [External Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=windows)

for **Private External Storage**:

```
var path = GetExternalFilesDir(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);
string fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(path.ToString(), "reservation.txt");
```

it will give a path like:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/package name/files/Download/reservation.txt
```

/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/package name/files/Download/reservation.txt

for **Public External Storage**:

```
var path = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);
string fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(path.ToString(), "reservation.txt");
```

it will give the path like:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Download/reservation.txt
```

so if you want to save files out of app Directory([Private External Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=windows#private-external-files)),you could save them to [Public External Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=windows#public-external-files)